# cursorTimeoutMillis is not working for sharded mongo cluster

Tags: php, mongodb

cursorTimeoutMillis is not working for sharded mongo cluster. I have set it to 20 min but still getting same exception after 10 min idle

> getMore: cursor didn't exist on server, possible restart or timeout?

It seems there is something related to sharded environment. The above setting are not applicable on the cursor open to shard.

Comment: Have you checked log? what does it say? Also mention your MongoDB version

Comment: it is happening due to cursor is getting killed over shards after 10 min. above timeout is applicable only for mongos not for the cursors for shards.

Comment: Well, without complete log it's difficult to pinpoint problem but `getMore` is not available in MongoDB versions prior than 3.2. See https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/getMore/

Comment: If possible, update your post to replicate problem you have (including sample documents, and query you are executing)

Comment: mongo version 2.6.11

Comment: i have set it "cursorTimeoutMillis" to 20 min for mongos. can i set it for mongod as well in sharded environment if yes then how?

Comment: See if this help you out. http://php.net/manual/en/mongocursor.timeout.php. Make it immutable. -1 value means forever. no timeout

Comment: sorry this is different, its client side.